# converting speech to text or values laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make an application that allows entering the students's grades. Indeed, I have a table with five columns: Student code -- First Name  ---- Last Name ---- Grade ---- Comment.

My question is the following: How can I enter each student's grades and comments by using speech recognition. Knowing that grade is a numeric value and comment is a string.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use google Speech-to-Text API to convert voice to text. https://cloud.google.com/products/ai#tab3

Comment: You probably want any frontend solution since php and laravel are for backend and can't help you with this task.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition